# How can I automate clicking and choosing from dropdown menu and saving?

Tags: selenium, automation

There is a database of students about 200, I need to choose 2 items from dropdown and click on save button at the end.
Doing manually takes about 5-6 sec. I want to know if it's possible to automate it?
Screenshots below:
[image: 1]

Then choosing 2 items:
[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Finally hit "save"button:
[image: 4]

Comment: Share html of dropdowns and save button in text format.

Answer (score 2):

In selenium you could do it like this:

```
WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the dropdown"));
Select dropdown= new Select(mySelectElement);
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);//select it by index
driver.findElement(By.id("id of your button")).click();
```